# Linq query using Equal is very slow, but contains not

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I have a problem using linq:
query that use "=" is very slow, I create it in this way:

```
predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Fields.Any(f => f.Name == name && f.ExpectedValue == value));
```

But, the "same" query using "Contains" is fast:

```
predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Fields.Any(f => f.Name == name && f.ExpectedValue.Contains(value)));
```

On my table I have indexes on "Name" and on "ExpectedValue".

Any suggestion?

Comment: `Contains` is fast than `==` because both are not same. Once contains found provided value it will return. I presume that `Contains` will have returned true in your test. Test with something that will return false will equally be as slow as `==`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thank you for the answer, but I need to suppose that every time the query is executed there is a result. There is a way, in linq, for emulate a "like 'value'" and not like '%value%'?

Comment: Check the SQL queries and the execution plans. It looks like the second query can't use the index for `ExpectedValue` and therefore maybe resolves to other indexes that happen to be faster.

Comment: What is the type of `ExpectedValue`?

Answer (score 1):

If your column is a VARCHAR, then you need to tell NHibernate to map it as AnsiString, otherwise it will send your parameter that you're querying through as a NVARCHAR and SQL server will then decide that it has to convert every VARCHAR value to NVARCHAR to do the comparison.

Because SQL server has to convert each VARCHAR field in the table to NVARCHAR, it doesn't use the index, and this can lead to severe query slowdown for no apparent reason.